# Site operation question: where did my second comment go?

Tags: support, specific-question, comments

Regarding: [What would a world population be after 300 years on a new planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/128442/what-would-a-world-population-be-after-300-years-on-a-new-planet)

I had two comments posted.  The first was the automatic comment when I marked the question as a duplicate.  I expected that to disappear should the question be voted a duplicate (which it was).

But I also had a second comment explaining why I had voted that way and including a link to a second useful question.  That one's gone, too.

Was that second question automatically removed like the first?  That is to say, does SE operate such that all comments (from the person who causes the first automatic "this could be a duplicate of..." comment) are removed? or was the comment removed manually by someone?

I have no feelings pro or con over the issue, I simply want to better understand how SE operates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That comment was deleted by Community.  There were no flags, so it must have been because of the closure.  I'm guessing that the system saw "duplicate" and a link and decided that this was another suggested duplicate.  If so, I'm surprised it doesn't take the length of the comment into account.

I've undeleted that comment because it had other useful information in it.  (And also to help anybody else who wants to investigate.)

Comment: I think the system doesn't actually keep track of which comments are autogenerated and which aren't, so it deletes for all the comments that have the word "duplicate" in them and a link to another question (even if it's not the same one that the question gets closed against). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195654/323179).

Comment: @Laurel it doesn't keep track; it's definitely pattern-matching.  I had thought there was a length constraint, so "possible duplicate of (URL)" would get deleted and "this might be a duplicate of (URL), but (300 more characters here)" wouldn't.  I guess not.